# Stuck on loops c#

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I calculated distance between a unit and a building, I put the distance inside a struct[] and sorted the distance smallest to largest. The AI goes to the closest building each time and this works as it is. Now my question is I want to add a check and remove the last line of code thats hardcoded to index 0. I want the AI to go to the next index each time the current index runs out of resources. How would i go about doing this? The struct populates with sorted distances each time the AI selects the closest building to bring resources from.

Would it be an if statement inside the for loop? Or another for loop with an if statement? Or do you change the indexes in the struct if the building is exhausted of resources?

```
    Destination2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Storehouses");        // storehouse distance should be based off  production
    
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    for (int i = 0; i < Destination2.Length; i++) // put in 10 storehouses, find the closest distance to the colonist
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
        buildingInformation[i].buildingID2 = Destination2[i];      // stores game objects 0,1
        

        Vector3 direction = (Destination2[i].transform.position - position);
        float distance = direction.sqrMagnitude;

        buildingInformation[i].buildingDistance2 = distance;
        Array.Sort<BuildingInformation>(buildingInformation, (x, y) => x.buildingDistance2.CompareTo(y.buildingDistance2));// smallest to largest
        
    }
    Supplier = buildingInformation[0].buildingID2;
```

Comment: First up: Sort your array after the for loop finishes.

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be to add a ridiculously large number to Distance if the storehouse is empty (```if (empty) distance += 1000000;```) And then the sort will push these to the bottom of the queue.

Comment: Ya I could just do a if (not empty) index[0] else if not empty index[1]  for the first 20 indexes, at least that way I could eventually have an else "not enough resources" message.

Comment: You'd probably do a ```for``` loop for that instead of a bunch of nested el-ifs, but yes =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Linqy pseudocode on how I'd approach it:

```
destination = storehouses
              .OrderBy( storehouse.distance )
              .FirstOrDefault( storehouse.contains(item) )
```

Although you're probably better off doing a single-pass iteration:

```
SomeType destination
foreach storehouse in storehouses
    if ( storehouse.contains(item) )
        if ( destination is null || storehouse.distance < destination.distance )
            destination = storehouse
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll stay away from Linq for now. I don't mind learning the basics w.o its shortcuts i also read that its sorting is very performance heavy.